# How to resolve given alphabet by using hash function

Tags: algorithm, hash

I'm preparing to exam from algorithms and have excercise which I do not understand.

1. Given keys put into distributed array (size n=7).

keys: PON, WTO, SRO, CZW, PIA, SOB, NIE.

with given alphabet:

[image: chart]

for hash function: hi = (Code(key) + i ) mod n

and Code(.) sum numbers of key letters according to numbers in alphabet.

Chose correct order of elements (order them like in the content of the task).

And I have anserws like:

[image: anserws]

First: I dont know what is 'i' in hash function. I know that 'PON" = 45, and I need to use modulo. I know that 'PON' need to be equal to 3 or 1, according to anserws, but I can'figure out how to get there.

Comment: Are you sure nothing else is shared in the question?

Comment: @Maruthi Adithya  Yes, I made sure.

Comment: Then, you can consider this as missing information and move to the next one!

Comment: @Maruthi Adithya haha, that's real question from previous year, so I'm don't want to skip it so easy.

Comment: Can you post the question picture here?

Comment: If PON = 45 then 45 mod n = 45 mod 7 = 3 mod 7. In the same way, if WTO = 58 then 58 mod 7 = 2 mod 7. No idea what `i` is for

Comment: @Maruthi Adithya I have only polish version of this.

Comment: @Artjom B damned, you have right, I was sure the results should be score of modulo, not "rest of them". Thank you.